# How do I remove/strip the row number from a variable in Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, row

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,time,date
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

fd = pd.read_csv('c:\\path\\to\\file.csv')

fd.columns = ['Date','Time']

datex = fd.Date
timex = fd.Time

timestr = datetime.strptime ( str(datex+" "+timex) , "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

So, what I'm trying to do is pass columns Date and Time to datetime.  There are two columns, date and time containing, obviously, the date and time.  But when I try the above method, I receive this error:

```
\n35760 08/07/2015 04:56\n35761 08/07/2015 04:57\n35762 08/07/2015 04:58\n35763 08/07/2015 04:59\ndtype: object' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
```

So, how do I either strip or remove \nXXXXX from datex and timex?  Or otherwise match the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# concatenate two columns ( date and time ) into one column that represent date time now into one columns
datetime = datex + timex
# remove additional characters and spaces from newly created datetime colummn
datetime = datetime.str.replace('\n\d+' , '').str.strip()
# then string should be ready to be converted to datetime easily
pd.to_datetime(datetime , format='%m/%d/%Y%H:%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas built-in parse_dates function :)

```
pd.read_csv('c:\\path\\to\\file.csv', parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried that.  It doesn't seem to work.